# Angular js simple app

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to build a simple web application based on Angular js.

I have a .json file like this, so I haven't manually inserted any information into the model.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Monuments Men",
        "year": 2014
    },
    {
        "name": "The Bourne Supremacy",
        "year": 2004        
    },
    {
        "name": "Toy Story",
        "year": 1995
    },
    {
        "name": "The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug",
        "year": 2013
    }
]
```

My controller gets the data and save into `$scope.movies`

In the same page, I have a form to insert a new film.

I am trying to get that new information, add/push it into the scope but doesn't work.

How can I get my list updated?

Comment: Post your controller and view code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="movieName" /><br/>
Year: <input type="text" ng-model="movieYear" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="Add" ng-click="addMovie()" />
```

Controller:

```
$scope.addMovie = function () {
    $scope.movies.push({name:$scope.movieName, year:$scope.movieYear});
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I put it back into the .json file?

Comment: Hi David, AngularJS is a client side framework and is therefore limited to doing things the web browser allows it to do via Javascript therefore it can't really write files (local storage or cookies aside).

Comment: You could send the new data back to the server (if you control the web application) and add it there.